# Prerender Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am using the Anuglar UI Bootstrap Modal to open a dialog with AngularJs and am experiencing a performance hit the first time the modal opens.  There is a noticeable stuttering as well as flashing of some of the hidden elements on the page as the dialog comes into view. All subsequent times the modal opens the dialog appears smoothly without any stuttering.

I assume this is due to the one-time computational overhead of compiling the view.  Is there any way to pre-compile the modal in the background of my app so that when the user opens the dialog it's ready to go.

I'm using the Angular UI Modal service like so

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl:'my-modal.html',
    controller:'MyModalCtrl'
});
```

I tried something like this for the directive but I need something that would work for the controller/dialog.

```
var directive = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>");
var instance = directive(scope.$new(true));
```

I am using angular 1.5.8 and angular-ui-bootstrap 1.3
This issue shows up in all browsers and on desktop and mobile, but it most noticeable on lower powered hardware (phone, tablet)

https://embed.plnkr.co/hDM6GrUh8droo988MOox/

Comment: never had this problem myself and have used their modals extensively, even with things like google maps inside. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: look. I use another approach: I create a div with the class modal, and in the div, I use <ng-include> to include the template immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Use resolve to make sure data is ready before the modal is even opened.

Here's an example from the docs.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

In addition, get away from {{}} on the modal (if that's what you're using) and use ng-bind instead.

Comment: I am already pre-loading the data the form uses so that doesn't seem to be the issue.  The view doesn't load any data when it opens. The problem seems to be in rendering the view.  It only happens the first time the modal is opened.  All other times it opens smoothly.

Comment: Ok, I was making an assumption because of I had limited info. As @charlietfl  mentioned can you create a demo that reproduces problem?

Comment: Here's my basic situation. This doesn't show the effect as dramatically but you can see the modal opens a little slower the first time compared to subsequent calls. Also this seems to be hardware dependant. Faster CPUs/GPUs might not show it. On an iPhone the effect is more pronounced for example. https://embed.plnkr.co/hDM6GrUh8droo988MOox/